# Use reference instead of pointers in google test fixture?

Tags: c++, testing, googletest

Here is the code:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

double sq(const double x) {
    return x*x;
}


class Sqtest : public ::testing::Test {
    protected:
        virtual void SetUp() {
            a = new int(1);
            b = new int(2);
            c = new int(3);
        }
        virtual void TearDown() {
            delete a;
            delete b;
            delete c;
        }
        int *a, *b, *c;
};

TEST_F (Sqtest, posnos) {
    EXPECT_EQ(1, sq(*a));
    EXPECT_EQ(4, sq(*b));
    EXPECT_EQ(9, sq(*c));
}
```

This is all nice, but what if in the function Sq I use reference, i.e.

```
double sq(const double& x) {
    return x*x;
}
```

How should I modify the fixture accordingly?

Comment: There's nothing to modify. But why are you using pointers?

Comment: I don't know, I used a template from SO. I also tried not to pointers, but the test failed to compile.

Comment: So is there a way to avoid pointer? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Just don't use them. It is easier than using them.

Comment: Could you please post an answer without using pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no really need to use pointer for this particular example. Let `Sqtest` members be of type `int` and you're done:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

int sq(int x)
{
    return x * x;
}


class Sqtest : public ::testing::Test
{
protected:
    virtual void SetUp() override
    {
        a = 1;
        b = 2;
        c = 3;
    }

    int a, b, c;
};

TEST_F(Sqtest, posnos)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(1, sq(a));
    EXPECT_EQ(4, sq(b));
    EXPECT_EQ(9, sq(c));
}
```